# Kubernetes ConfigMap issue

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I'm struggling to hunt down the cause of this error, though it seems like a string/bool/Dict or some value is not where ConfigMap wants it. I've verified that the JSON is valid that I'm passing, so that's where I started and everything was legal.

```
- name: Create appsettings ConfigMap
  k8s:
    state: "{{ service_state }}"
    kubeconfig: "{{ tempdir.path }}/.kubeconfig"
    resource_definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: ConfigMap
      metadata:
        name: appsettingconf
        namespace: "{{ cust_reports_namespace }}"
      data:
        "app-settings.json": "{{ lookup('template', 'appsettings.json.j2') }}"
```

ERROR:
1.ConfigMap.Data: ReadString: expects \\\\\" or n, but found {, error found in #10 byte of ...|gs.json\\\\\":{\\\\\"applicati|..., bigger context ...|{\\\\\"apiVersion\\\\\":\\\\\"v1\\\\\",\\\\\"data\\\\\":{\\\\\"app-settings.json\\\\\":{\\\\\"applicationSettings\\\\\":{\\\\\"reportingApiUrl\\\\\":\\\\\"http://a|...\",\"reason\":\"Invalid\",\"details\":{\"causes\":[{\"reason\":\"FieldValueInvalid\",\"message\":\"Invalid value: \\\\\"{\\\\\\\

Comment: are you encoding the JSON somehow? I had a similar error with secrets that arose because the secret wasn't encoded properly

Comment: @prnvnb, If I'm encoding it's not intentional. I basically took the config that I had for a secret and didn't encode it because there's not sensitive data here. Any suggestions on how to move forward?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. template | tojson | b64encode. Always something simple....